# React - Do next step after finishing upload to firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

after hard working, Finally, I can upload data to firebase, I only last step that check data uploaded completely before come back main App, coding described as follow:

```
upload = () => { 
   fb.database().ref('/posts').push({
     item ...
   })
}

console = () => {
   this.upload();
   // Missing 
   this.comeBack();
}
```

At missing position, I need do stuff related loading indicator to check finished before switch next step, appreciate your interest, thanks!

*ps: sorry, I didn't have what I've tried because I still don't know where to begin*